# Display List with Lists in primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to display below list of list of object in table.

```
    [[name1,v1],[name2,v2],[name...n,v...n],
    [name1,v1_2],[name2,v2_2],[name..n,v n...n]...]
```

the goal is the table:

```
name 1 | nam 2 | name n
v1     | v2    | v...n
v1_2   | v2_2  | v...
```

Comment: That's not a job for PrimeFaces. Convert the data structure in your backing code.

Comment: Yup. Give the view the model it expects. If you give it the wrong model, the view cannot do much with it.